# Dates showing up with a formula ( =TODAY()-cell) that I don't want there

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the following formula in my sheet: `=TODAY()-D3`

This takes the date (a due date on a customer order) and puts the number of days it is late in the next cell.

This is working great. But if the D Cell is empty, it will post today's date in the E cell. I don't want that as it looks unorganized, and draws attention to empty rows we don't need to look at.

I have included a [Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17FOh_4FYGlCIETcYfzrAouXMN8_YhMOZZAbwsDd5SN8/edit?usp=sharing) to the sheet I made a copy of.

Can anyone offer some help on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try to wrap it into simple `IF` statement like:

```
=IF(D3<>"", TODAY()-D3, )
```

but best would be to use `ARRAYFORMULA` in **E3** cell to auto-fill it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(D3:D), TODAY()-D3:D, ))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clue me into why the `ARRAYFORMULA` is better? If the `IF` statement works just as well why not do that? Does `ARRAYFORMULA` do a better job?

Comment: it does better job, because if statement needs to be placed on every row. arrayformula needs to be present only on first row. check your sheet

Comment: So in the future, the part that denotes `(LEN(D3:D)` is used to select D3 - infinity D?

Sounds great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yes... range is from D3 to D.infinity and LEN formula checks if there is anything typed in Dx cell